# SQL View creation error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to copy a view from one database to another and get the error :

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vwPAProjects_Summary_New_2 
>   Line 2
>   *Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate "dbo.GetContractName", or the name is ambiguous*

The view I am copying over is:

```
USE [GRAUD]
GO
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[vwPAProjects_Summary_New_2]    Script Date: 11/07/2012 11:57:30 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwPAProjects_Summary_New_2] AS 
select
 dbo.GetContractName(PAPROJNUMBER) 'CONTRACT',
PACONTNUMBER,
isnull(dbo.GetEmployeeName(PABusMgrID),dbo.GetContractPartner(PACONTNUMBER)) 'Project Manager ID',
case PASTAT
when 1 then 'Open'
else 'Closed'
end 'Status',
case PAProjectType
when 3 then 'Fixed Price'
else 'Time and Materials'
end 'Project Type',
PAProject_Fee_Amount 'Project Fee Amount',
PAFTotalCost 'Forecast Total Cost',
(PAProject_Fee_Amount - PAFTotalCost) 'Forcast Profit',
case
    when PAProject_Fee_Amount = 0 then '0.00%'
    else cast(cast(((PAProject_Fee_Amount - PAFTotalCost)/PAProject_Fee_Amount)*100 as decimal(19,2)) as varchar(21)) + '%'
end 'Forcast %',
PAPostedBillingsN 'Actual Billings',
PAPostedTotalCostN 'Actual Total Cost',
(PAPostedBillingsN - PAPostedTotalCostN) 'Current Actual Profit',
case
    when PAPostedBillingsN = 0 then '0.00%'
    else cast(cast(((PAPostedBillingsN - PAPostedTotalCostN)/PAPostedBillingsN)*100 as decimal(19,2)) as varchar(21)) + '%'
end 'Current %'

from PA01201
where PASTAT = 1
```

Can anybody advise on how I can get this to copy over?  It has worked on other databases after I have copied it over but I cannot see any differences that would stop it this time?

Comment: Well, it says right there in the error message, doesn't it? First thing you want to check is whether `dbo.GetContractName` exists in the database you are trying to create the view in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy over the function `dbo.GetContractName` first, then you should find the view copies too.

Comment: Cheers.  sometimes the most obvious solutions are the last to find.